# What PHP class executes the SQL to select models and collections from the database?

Tags: magento2, database, model, factory, repository

When I have a PHP model or collection of a Magento entity (such as a product or customer), what PHP class(es) is in charge of constructing and executing the SQL that selects that model or collection of models from the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most circumstances, entity models inherit from `AbstractModel`, resource models, which serves as an adapter between an entity model and ORM, inherit from `AbstractDb`, and collections inherit from `AbstractCollection`.

Take a look at the following classes:

- `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel`
- `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`
- `Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`
- `Magento\Framework\DB\Select`